# How to load Iframe shared style and script resources only once from source to source?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have one page with navigation bar; which loads only once; and it has an iframe in it. The source of the iframe is changed by using links inside navigation bar of the container page. The sources are on the same domain.

The problem is;

On my development environment I track that it creates fresh requests for styles and scripts when I change the source of the iframe even though the styles and scripts don't change source to source for the iframe.

My question is;

How can I achive iframe to load styles and scripts only once(probably from the cache) for the sources?

I tried removing iframe styles and scripts definition since the main page and iframe sources use the same resource but it doesnt work on that way.

Comment: It should be cached... If you are not seeing it cached, your dev tool might be set up to not cache or you have the wrong headers set. Maybe the iframe solution is the wrong solution and you should be a proper SPA.